# SQL Server Management Studio 2016

Tags: sql-server, ssms, azure-sql-database

i would like to ask if anybody having the similar problems like me.

i have downloaded the newest SQL Server Management Studio 2016 Preview from Microsoft web site, and after i installed it (successfully and i need to restart my notebook said the warning box) then, suddenly nothing happens, there is a folder on the start menu that says SQL Server Management Studio 2016, but the folder is self is empty and i do not see the app, first i thought must be i missed something, so i went back and repair those SSMS (through the Repair Menu), but still it is giving me the same error, does anybody here have the similar problem and a way out of it?, since i need this SSMS 2016 to query to my Azure SQL Database.

Thanks!.

Roland

Comment: Not the same but related, I installed it and didn't see SSMS in the folder and thought that I had missed something in the install. Turns out that SSMS now comes as a separate install from the Tools link on the install menu. Took me a few minutes to see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happened with me few times when i tried to install it in not the Administrator mode.
So, try to do that in elevated mode, if that will not help, try to download it again or just rollback to the [older version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238488.aspx) (2014), as it works perfectly with the SQL Azure. SSMS 2016 is still in preview, so the unexpected behavior may happen.

Comment: the problem is right now my notebook is only set to use one user and that is my user as an administrator, but right now i am going try to repair it but using administrator option on the right click menu.

Answer (score 1):

So, it turns out that in Windows 10, all the start menu options may not show up. Try visiting `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft SQL Server 2016 RC3` in your File explorer to see if the SSMS shortcut is available there.

Comment: btw i am using windows 7 for now, and in that folder i could not open it, i need to reclaim the ownership of the folder.

Comment: Thanks... it worked for me. For anyone else facing this issue, folder mentioned in path above as "Microsoft SQL Server 2016 RC3" can be "Microsoft SQL Server Tools 17" or something like this depending on your version. :)